# Get Select data option and populate hidden field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

i need help, i have a Select and i need to populate a hidden field with the data of each option (not the value) check the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#retailer_id').change(function() {
var $selected = $('#retailer_id option:selected');
$('#slug_title').val($(this).val());
});
});
        </script>
<select class="textbox2" id="retailer_id" name="retailer_id">
<option value="">--- Please select store ---</option>
<?php
$sql_retailers = smart_mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cashbackengine_retailers WHERE status='active' ORDER BY title ASC");
while ($row_retailers = mysql_fetch_array($sql_retailers))
{
if ($retailer_id == $row_retailers['retailer_id']) $selected = " selected=\"selected\""; else $selected = "";
echo "<option data-slug_title=\"".$row_retailers['slug_title']."\" value=\"".$row_retailers['retailer_id']."\"".$selected.">".$row_retailers['title']."      </option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Right now its populating with the retailer_id, but i need to get the value returned on (`data-slug_title=\"".$row_retailers['slug_title']."\"`)

**EDITED**

HTML output:

```
<select class="textbox2" id="retailer_id" name="retailer_id">
<option value="">--- Please select store ---</option>
<option data-slug="casas-bahia-teste" value="4">Casas Bahia</option>
<option data-slug="direct-cosmetics" value="6">Direct Cosmetics</option>
<option data-slug="extra" value="3">Extra</option>
<option data-slug="flowers-direct" value="5">Flowers Direct</option>
<option data-slug="gem-motoring-assist" value="1">GEM Motoring Assist</option>
<option data-slug="pc-world-business" value="7">PC World Business</option>
<option data-slug="ponto-frio" value="10">Ponto Frio</option>
<option data-slug="red-house" value="2">Red House</option>
</select>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $('#retailer_id').change( function() {
var $selected = $('#retailer_id option:selected');
$('input[name=slug]').val($selected.data('slug'));
});
});
        </script>
```

Comment: so `echo "<option data-slug_title=\"".$row_retailers['slug_title']."\" value=\"".$row_retailers['slug_title']."\"".$selected.">".$row_retailers['title']."</option>";`

Comment: But i still need the value to get the retailer_id

Comment: do you need to return `data-slug_title`!?

Comment: yes, right now the data its correct when i see the source of the page, but its not populating the hidden field.

Comment: can you show your html result of option?

Comment: Just did, please check, thanks :)

Comment: i'v tested your code it seems ok!

`<option data-slug_title="casas-bahia-teste" value="4" selected="selected">casas-bahia-teste</option>`